# Is the IRS open December 26?

Tags: irs, holidays

Does anyone know if the IRS is open for phone calls on December 26?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The IRS takes phone calls [Monday-Friday](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Telephone-Assistance). December 26, 2015 is a Saturday.

Comment: Goodness, with all these days off school I lost track of the days of the week.

Comment: The question might arise for future years too, as phrased it's not specific to 2015